# How to show the date more than one year

Tags: amcharts

As soon as my date is more than `one year`, the `amcharts` will not show the graph. I think(Maybe) the reason is that the `format` of date in  `CategoryAxis` only has the `Month`, then if there is more than one year, it will not make sense, I try to change it, but it does not work, so how to solve it, here is my code:
(The data is inputed, actually I don't what's the utilities of `fromDate` and `toDate`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mask = '<div class="k-loading-mask" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"><span class="k-loading-text" style="text-indent: 0; width:60%; top: 40%; left: 20%; background-color: #0F0;">Please wait while the Back Test results are being generated. <br />This could take up to 30 seconds.</span><div class="k-loading-image" style="display:none;"></div><div class="k-loading-color"></div></div>';

    var fromDate = new Date(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var toDate = new Date(2016, 2, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    AmCharts.ready(function () {
        drawStockChartData();
    });

    function drawStockChartData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/TestAmStockChartData",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                for (var i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++) {
                    result[i].Date = new Date(parseInt(result[i].Date.slice(6, 19)));
                }
                createStockChart(result);
            },
        });
    }



    function createStockChart(data) {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();


        // DATASETS
        var dataSet1 = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet1.color = "#b0de09";
        dataSet1.fieldMappings = [{
            fromField: "NAV",
            toField: "NAV"
        },
        {
            fromField: "PNL",
            toField: "PNL"
        }];
        dataSet1.dataProvider = data;
        dataSet1.categoryField = "Date";

        chart.dataSets = [dataSet1];

        // PANELS
        var stockPanel1 = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis = true;
        stockPanel1.title = "NAV";
        stockPanel1.percentHeight = 100;
        stockPanel1.eraseAll = false;
        //stockPanel.addLabel(0, 100, "Click on the pencil icon on top-right to start drawing", "center", 16);

        var graph1 = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph1.title = "NAV";
        graph1.valueField = "NAV";
        graph1.bullet = "round";
        graph1.bulletColor = "#FFFFFF";
        graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#00BBCC";
        graph1.bulletBorderAlpha = 1;
        graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
        graph1.bulletSize = 7;
        graph1.lineThickness = 2;
        graph1.lineColor = "#00BBCC";
        graph1.useDataSetColors = false;
        graph1.comparable = true;
        graph1.compareField = "HSI";
        stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph1);

        var stockLegend1 = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockLegend1.valueTextRegular = " ";
        stockLegend1.markerType = "none";
        stockPanel1.stockLegend = stockLegend1;
        stockPanel1.drawingIconsEnabled = true;

        chart.panels = [stockPanel1];

        // OTHER SETTINGS
        var scrollbarSettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
        scrollbarSettings.graph = graph1;
        scrollbarSettings.updateOnReleaseOnly = false;
        chart.chartScrollbarSettings = scrollbarSettings;

        var cursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
        cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
        chart.chartCursorSettings = cursorSettings;

        var panelsSettings = new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
        panelsSettings.creditsPosition = "bottom-right";
        //panelsSettings.creditsPosition = null;
        panelsSettings.marginRight = 16;
        panelsSettings.marginLeft = 16;
        chart.panelsSettings = panelsSettings;

        // PERIOD SELECTOR
        var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
        periodSelector.position = "bottom";
        periodSelector.periods = [{
            period: "DD",
            count: 10,
            label: "10 days"
        }, {
            period: "MM",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 month"

        }, {
            period: "YYYY",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 year"
        }, {
            period: "YTD",
            label: "YTD"
        }, {
            period: "MAX",
            label: "MAX"
        }];
        chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;

        chart.write('divPnlAmChart');
    };

</script>
```

I test that the `breakpoint` can not enter the

```
function createStockChart(data) {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
```

and can not show the `data` when there is more that `1 year`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me going by the sample data format posted before: https://jsfiddle.net/zr35pot0/1/. Can you post your data? Better yet, post a fiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @ xorspark  is there anyway to see the explicit `data` in `dataset` quickly?

Comment: Use the browser's debugger to add a breakpoint in the success callback and call `console.log` on the result variable.

Comment: @xorspark sorry, which variable should I watch, the `data` is the original inputed including lots of properties not only `PNL` 'NAV' 'CashLeft`'

Comment: Going by your code sample, watch `data` or watch the `result`.  Alternatively, look at your browser's developer toolbar's network tab and paste the response from the AJAX request to /Home/TestAmStockChartData if that makes it easier. Either way, it seems like there's something wrong with your data (particularly the dates) and not the chart code itself as the fiddle demonstrates.

Comment: @ xorspark Please see the updated question, the `breakpoint` stop at `function createStockChart(data)` , and it keep running with no error no result no stop,that's why?

Comment: Can't say for sure why it's not stopping without seeing it for myself. Try putting the breakpoint inside the function rather than at the definition line? Or look at the network tab like I mentioned earlier and get the response output from your /Home/TestAmStockChartData endpoint that way.

Comment: @ xorspark , thx a lot, by way, how to call for the value of `balloon`, i want to define `balloontext` as `tiltie fo graph` + `value`?

Comment: Set the [`balloonText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#balloonText) property in your stockGraph objects to `"[[title]] [[value]]"`. `[[title]]` maps to either the dataSet title or your stockGraph's title; if both are set, then the stockGraph takes priority. `[[value]]` maps to the value at that point. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zr35pot0/2/